# 'docker-compose up' hangs when attaching files for running Django server in virtualization

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run Django inside a Docker container and connect to it using VS code remote, but it keeps hanging at the attach part.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/datadrivendiscovery/images/primitives:ubuntu-bionic-python36-v2020.1.9

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/app

WORKDIR /app/

EXPOSE 8000

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 /app/manage.py runserver"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .\
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I don't have a database setup so I don't have that in the yml.

Comment: Container folder for sources is `app`, not `code` and looks like you correctly do copy sources inside docker image so try removing wrong and unnecessary volume from your docker-compose config. Also you don't have to define command again in docker-compose - you already have it in your image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I made the changes to my code and to the stack question. Unfortunately it still hands : [

Comment: Please elaborate what does "hangs" mean. What is the container status in `docker ps -a`? Can you access localhost:8000?

Comment: @IvanStarostin So it just does "attaching <app name>....." and that just goes forever. I cannot access localhost:8000 when I try to go there it just gives me not found. I unfortunately can't run 'docker ps -a' because it's hanging so I can't type any commands while this is running.

Comment: run `docker-compose up -d` to detach from started process immediately.